# Azure Pipelines build fails with "Error response from daemon: Container <id> is not running"

Tags: azure-pipelines

My Azure Pipelines build fails during the CmdLine stage with `Error response from daemon: Container 6c04267ea73602db828802df820c5c33cf95223ad0dcd0e3ef73b545d51f3bfa is not running`.

My `azure-pipelines.yml` is:

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-2019
container: my-docker-container

steps:
  - script: |
      echo 'run build script'
```

And the `Dockerfile` for `my-docker-container` is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809
# Do stuff
ENTRYPOINT ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
```

What do I need to fix to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `ENTRYPOINT [...]` line from `Dockerfile`. The build pipeline needs `ENTRYPOINT` to be `cmd.exe`; I don't know why.

You can include `SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]` in `Dockerfile` and it will not affect the build.

To run Powershell scripts in your pipeline, change `- script` to [`- powershell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#powershell).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml i think this describes why you cannot have entrypoint in the docker file, so its documented\well known

Comment: @4c74356b41 I can't find this information in the doc. Perhaps are you referring to a requirement for Linux containers? If not could you point it out for me?

Comment: @4c74356b41 I see. I haven't seen any documentation for `ENTRYPOINT` in Windows containers, which is what I'm using. I did look through the build logs but I couldn't find any clues in there. All commands passed to docker in the log should work in powershell, so I'm guessing it is an internal script which depends on cmd or associated programs.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the reminder. I couldn't mark it as an answer until today.